# Header has been moved to react-navigation-stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

After upgrading the react-navigation to v4.0, i am facing the following issue.

react-native v60.0
react-navigation v4.0.0[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you already have `react-navigation-stack` added to your `package.json`:

Search in your code for the line:

```
import { Header } from 'react-navigation';
```

or similar. And replace with:

```
import { Header } from 'react-navigation-stack';
```

Comment: My code does not use Header. At all. Must come from a dependency but I'm unable to figure out which one, and npm outdated is happy.

Answer (score 0):

A lot has been changed since latest react-navigation release(v4)

In your case make sure that you have all the dependencies installed that are now a part of react-navigation.

1. Make sure you followed [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html) for basic setup and have all the dependencies installed.
2. You have to install react-navigation-stack dependency in order to use createStackNavigator now so in your terminal(project folder)

   run - yarn add react-navigation-stack.For more info follow [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html)
3. if you are using tabs as well in your application, install react-navigation-tabs as well. For more info follow [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#docsNav)

Comment: Already installed those  dependencies, react-navigation-stack ,react-navigation-tabs and react-navigation-drawer but no luck!

Answer (score 0):

All migration instructions are mentioned in the release notes

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/releases/tag/v4.0.0